# Referencing a C# object by calculation

Tags: c#

I have 8 picture boxes, named p1 through p8.

I would like to change the backcolor of one of those picture boxes, depending on the result of a calculation.

I can create a string beginning with the letter 'p' and affix the calculated number to that string.

I am looking for a clever way to reference a picture box with this string (eg. "p4"). My question is, is this possible?

Comment: Why not use an array or something similar instead?

Comment: Instead of searching by name use a collection that holds all your images and access them by index: `myImages[0].Colur = ...`. What kind of app is it? ASP? Winforms? WPF...?

Comment: In WinForms, you can access a control with something like: `this.Controls["p4"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *really* want to refer to them by a string like `p4` then put them in a dictionary

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string,PictureBox>();
dict.add("p1",myP1dict);
dict.add("p2",myP2dict);
// etc
dict["p2"].BackgroundColor = newColor;
```

More likely, you could just put them in an array

```
var arr = new PictureBox[8]
arr[0] = myPictBox1
arr[1] = myPictBox2
//etc
arr[1].BackgroundColor = newColor;
```

And refer to them by index.